# How do you compare characters in java?

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, char

How do you compare characters (like Strings, such as variable.equals(a))?  Also, what am I doing wrong in this line of code:

```
    char num[] = new char[10];
    char num[0] = ' ';
    char num[1] = ' ';
    char num[2] = ' ';
    char num[3] = ' ';
    char num[4] = ' ';
    char num[5] = ' ';
    char num[6] = ' ';
    char num[7] = ' ';
    char num[8] = ' ';
    char num[9] = ' ';
```

I'm trying to make a array of characters, but it's giving me an error message.

Comment: char[] characterArray = new char[] {'a','b','c'}

Answer (score 7):

That would probably be:

```
char[] num = new char[10];
num[0] = ' ';
num[1] = ' ';
num[2] = ' ';
num[3] = ' ';
num[4] = ' ';
num[5] = ' ';
num[6] = ' ';
num[7] = ' ';
num[8] = ' ';
num[9] = ' ';
```

or just do this:

```
char[] num = new char[] { 'K', 'E', 'V', 'I', 'N' };
```

To compare character you can use the operators **==** or **<** or **>**

```
char x = 'x';
char y = 'y';

if( x <> y )
{
    //do magic
}

if( x == y )
{
    //do black magic
}
```

Comment: What about the question about comparisons?

Comment: I just added some examples

Answer (score 4):

To create a new character array:

```
char[] characterArray = new char[] {'a','b','c'}
```

to compare characters you can use `==`

```
if (yourVariable == 'A') { ...}
```

Comment: And you can make a character array from a String, too: `char[] characterArray = "abc".toCharArray()`, which saves some typing.

Answer (score 1):

That is what are you doing wrong... you variable name is `num` so if you want to put some char in the position X, you just need to call `num`.

```
char num[] = new char[10];
num[0] = ' ';
num[1] = ' ';
num[2] = ' ';
num[3] = ' ';
num[4] = ' ';
num[5] = ' ';
num[6] = ' ';
num[7] = ' ';
num[8] = ' ';
num[9] = ' ';
```

To compare, you may use `==` as always you do.

Answer (score 1):

remove the successive 'char' keywords

```
char num[] = new char[10];
num[0] = ' ';
num[1] = ' ';
//etc
```

Comment: +1  Because you answered the "What am I doing wrong" part of his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num[6]>num[5])
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

I guess, that should do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
char[] num = new char[10];
```

you are creating an array of char ,instead of a char

for char comparison, you can just use '==' as an int:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'a';
if( a == b ){...}
```