# How do I access a character greater than the length of a string by repeating the string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a problem where a string for eg. `"dancing"` is given and two indexes `n=3,m=10` is given. We have to ***check*** whether the ***char*** at both index is ***same***.

Which is true in this case when the string is repeated as `[dancingdancing]`. The 3rd and 10th character is `n`. How do I solve this in `java`?

Comment: Use the modulo operator `%`

Comment: [Concatenate or Merge strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608315/concatenate-or-merge-strings-java) [How can i access a char in string in at specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297288/how-can-i-access-a-char-in-string-in-at-specific-number) [How do you compare characters in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474475/how-do-you-compare-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the characters at two indexes are same by updating the value of the second index provided such as :

```
String str = "dancing";
int first = 3;
int second = 10;

first = first % str.length();
second = second % str.length();
Assert.assertTrue(str.charAt(first) == str.charAt(second))
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But why do we use Assert?

Comment: @HarshRaj Just to confirm that for the given input, your expected result is achieved. It's just a way to write it, you could, for example, validate that using `System.out.println(str.charAt(first) == str.charAt(second))` as well.

Comment: Naman This approach is failing for some input such as "mail" for index 5 and 14.

Comment: @HarshRaj If the first index as well could be greater than the length as well, just repeat the same process. Updated in the answer.